# Iterative sum and multiplication product in matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration

Lets say i have a starting value,multiplication value and array. I want to calculate sum and multiplication product similar to "cumsum" (i suppose i need some kind of iteration).

```
AvgPlusDM = zeros(1,size);
AvgPlusDM(1) = 10;
for i = 2:size
        AvgPlusDM(i) = AvgPlusDM(i-1) + SF * ( PlusDM(i) - AvgPlusDM(i-1) );
end;
```

SF - constant, PlusDM - array.
I need to do this as quick as possible and this loop is too slow. How else can it be done?

Comment: You can use `arrayfun` to increase the speed.

Comment: You could try to code directly the solution to the recurrence relation inside the loop. However, I would time both approaches because it is not obvious which one is faster: `a_n = (1-SF)^(n-1)*a_1 + SF*((1-SF)^(n-2)*b_2 + (1-SF)^(n-3)*b_3 + ... + SF*b_n)`, where `a_n = AvgPlusDM(n)` and `b_n=PlusDM(n)`.